# Where can I find a valid SVG XML Schema (for ecore generation)?

Tags: xml, xsd, svg, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I tried importing the [SVG XML Schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/SVG.xsd) into EMF, to obtain the SVG metamodel in ecore. However, the import failed due to the schema not being valid: indeed, svg.xsd references [XMLSchema.dtd](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/XMLSchema.dtd), which itself references [datatypes.dtd](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/datatypes.dtd), which does not exist!

Consequently, I tried downloading the necessary files from the svg website (svg.xsd, XMLSchema.dtd, [xlink.xsd](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/xlink.xsd), [xml.xsd](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/xml.xsd)), and the missing datatypes.dtd, from [another location](http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd). However, I keep getting many errors when validating the schema, e.g.

```
Error: XSD: An attribute reference may not have a type
Error: XSD: An <all> content model may not be nested within another content model
```

and so on.

Does anyone know where I could find a valid svg XML Schema, or an svg ecore metamodel whose instances are serialized in valid svg?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The SVG XML Schema you refer to is from an old working draft of svg. There's currently no officially supported XML schema for SVG 1.1. SVG Tiny 1.2 does provide an [official RelaxNG schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVGTiny12/schema.html) (which is only for SVG Tiny 1.2, not for all of SVG 1.1). For SVG 1.1 there's a [DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/svgdtd.html) available, but no XML schema.

See [previous discussions](http://www.w3.org/Search/Mail/Public/search?type-index=www-svg&index-type=t&keywords=xsd&search=Search) and feel free to join in the discussion by sending email to www-svg@w3.org.