# Validating SVG file in PHP with XMLReader

Tags: php, xml, svg, xmlreader, xml-validation

I am validating a SVG document (which I believe to be valid) against the SVG spec. I'm using XMLReader in PHP, and would rather stick with that as I will be using XMLReader elsewhere; that said if there are other stream-based readers that will do this easier/better, do let me me know.

OK, here's some code:

```
    // Set some values for the purpose of this example
    $this->path = '/Users/jon/Development/Personal/Visualised/master/test-assets/import-png.svg';
    $xsdPath = '/Users/jon/Development/Personal/Visualised/master/test-assets/xsd/SVG.xsd';

    $reader = new XMLReader();
    $reader->open($this->path);
    $valid = $reader->setSchema($xsdPath);
    $reader->close();
```

OK, so the XSD files I've got in my `xsd` folder are:

- [SVG.xsd](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/SVG.xsd)
- [xlink.xsd](http://www.w3.org/XML/2008/06/xlink.xsd)
- [xml.xsd](http://www.w3.org/2000/10/xml.xsd)

It seems that the parser imports the second and third XSD from the first - I want any dependencies to be stored on disk, not retrieved from the internet.

OK, here's the output:

```
    XMLReader::setSchema(): Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Skipping import of schema located at '/Users/jon/Development/Personal/Visualised/master/test-assets/xsd/xml.xsd' for the namespace 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace', since this namespace was already imported with the schema located at 'http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd'. in /Users/jon/Development/Personal/Visualised/master/lib/Visualised/Document.php on line 45

    Warning: XMLReader::setSchema(): Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attribute': The attribute 'type' is not allowed. in /Users/jon/Development/Personal/Visualised/master/lib/Visualised/Document.php on line 45

    Warning: XMLReader::setSchema(): Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attribute': The attribute 'type' is not allowed. in /Users/jon/Development/Personal/Visualised/master/lib/Visualised/Document.php on line 45

    Warning: XMLReader::setSchema(): Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attribute': The attribute 'type' is not allowed. in /Users/jon/Development/Personal/Visualised/master/lib/Visualised/Document.php on line 45

    Warning: XMLReader::setSchema(): Unable to set schema. This must be set prior to reading or schema contains errors. in /Users/jon/Development/Personal/Visualised/master/lib/Visualised/Document.php on line 45
```

It seems like maybe I have imported the wrong version of a schema somewhere - I found all the XSD docs just through a web search. Any ideas?

Edit: the last error suggests the schema should be set before reading the document. OK, so I've changed the code to this:

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$valid = $reader->setSchema($xsdPath);
$reader->open($this->path);
$reader->close();
```

-- some of the initial warnings go, but I still get the `Unable to set schema` one.

Comment: Hmm, I've converted the svg XSD to RelaxNG [here](http://debeissat.nicolas.free.fr/XSDtoRNG.php) and switched `setSchema` to `setRelaxNGSchema` - and I get the same result.

Comment: Interestingly, `setRelaxNGSchema` seems to need to be called after the document is set (source: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46978), whereas I think it's the other way around for `setSchema`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510986/where-can-i-find-a-valid-svg-xml-schema-for-ecore-generation.

Comment: Much appreciated @ErikDahlström - I will follow that up when I get a moment (if my PHP errors turn out to be due to my using the wrong XSD files, or if I can use a DTD in preference to an XSD/NRG then you can have the bounty I planned for this question).

Comment: @ErikDahlström - thank you! I'd been fighting with this one for ages. With a bit of code fiddling I've now successfully validated against the DTD successfully. If you'd like +100, please add your link below; I'll set up a bounty and award it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSD file for SVG you link to is from an old working draft version of SVG 1.1. There's currently no officially supported XML schema for SVG 1.1. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3511537/109374) for more details.

Comment: Will award the bounty tomorrow - it won't permit it immediately.