# Security implications of letting users render own SVG files

Tags: php, xml, security, svg, filtering

I plan to let website users upload their own SVG documents and render them with `inkscape` or `svg2pdf`. The users will either be unauthenticated or go through a trivial sign-up process, so I would expect some hack attempts. What filtering can I do to minimise security threats?

- Inkscape doesn't seem to be bothered by [JavaScript onload tags](http://html5sec.org/#11) and happily renders the content without anything untoward happening (that said, I can't get Firefox 10 to cough up an alert box either using that approach).
- I am concerned that an `<image xlink:href />` tag could link to a huge or malformed bitmap image using an external URI - which theoretically could crash the service. Is there an easy way to traverse the XML document to filter these? I can do this easily with XMLReader of course, but wonder if I might have to deal with things like `&#111;nload` for 'onload' (though Firefox just rejected it as invalid, so perhaps this is a needless worry). Sidenode: images in themselves are acceptable but I think I'd either require them to either be inline `data:` or whitelist acceptable target URIs, with filesize limitations.
- Are there any SVG directives (in particular that render text) that could include the text contents of system files, such as `/etc/passwd` etc?
- One approach I could also take is validation against the SVG spec. That's the subject of another question I've asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651493/validating-svg-file-in-php-with-xmlreader).

I'm using PHP 5.2 with XMLReader and XMLWriter, though other PHP stream-based systems would be acceptable. Systems are OS X 10.6.8 for dev, and LAMP on production.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there any SVG directives (in particular that render text) that could include the text contents of system files, such as /etc/passwd etc?

You need to make sure XXE attacks are not possible for your specific implementation, [see here](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/611.html).

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that. If you've any ideas how to replicate such an attack, I'll have something concrete to test against.