# (PHP) How can I validate the .svg (file upload)

Tags: php, svg, getimagesize

I have a problem validating a file upload.

To be sure a user uploads a valid image (not a file with extension .jpg or .png,...) one can use `getimagesize()`. For example: [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) .

But what about an .svg file? The function `getimagesize()` returns nothing when I use `print_r()`. How could I be sure that user uploads a .svg file, not a file with extension .svg (virus.svg)?

Comment: try to parse it with an xml parser perhaps?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651493/validating-svg-file-in-php-with-xmlreader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating SVG file in PHP with XMLReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651493/validating-svg-file-in-php-with-xmlreader)

Comment: @gkalikapersaud Thanks but it's not.
They have the file path. I don't. I use `<input type='file'>`. And because some reasons, the browsers don't let me get the full path or I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload)

Answer (score -1):

If you're OK with using external scripts, you can use the SVG Sanitize package: https://packagist.org/packages/enshrined/svg-sanitize

While its primary purpose is sanitation, as a by-product of that process, it will also ensure your SVG is valid.

```
use enshrined\svgSanitize\Sanitizer;

// Create a new sanitizer instance
$sanitizer = new Sanitizer();

// Load the dirty svg (if it's an SVG file)
$dirtySVG = file_get_contents('filthy.svg');

// if it's a base64 encoded string, you can alternatively use the following
$base64_str = str_replace('data:image/svg+xml;base64,', '', $b64_string);
$base64_str = str_replace(' ', '+', $base64_str);
$dirtySVG = base64_decode($base64_str);

// Pass it to the sanitizer and get it back clean
if(!$cleanSVG = $sanitizer->sanitize($dirtySVG)){
    //if this fails, the SVG was not valid.
}

// Now do what you want with your validated and clean SVG/XML data
```