# Trouble using xjc for SVG.xsd

Tags: java, svg, jaxb, xjc

I am using xjc.bat to create jaxb files for the svg schema.

On the command line I enter:

`xjc http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/SVG.xsd -verbose`

My output is:

`parsing a schema...
[ERROR] http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/datatypes.dtd
unknown location`

Failed to parse a schema.

It's kind of a simple question, I don't know what I'm doing wrong and can't really find any leads to investigate.

Anyone know how to run it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in a previous question:

[Where can I find a valid SVG XML Schema (for ecore generation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510986/where-can-i-find-a-valid-svg-xml-schema-for-ecore-generation)

As that states, there is no valid SVG schema.

You can generate the jaxb classes by running the following:

xjc -dtd http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11-flat-
20110816.dtd